# What, if any, exemptions exist to 28 U.S. Code § 516?

Tags: united-states, us-federal-government

[28 U.S. Code § 516](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/28/516) states:

> Except as otherwise authorized by law, the conduct of litigation in which the United States, an agency, or officer thereof is a party, or is interested, and securing evidence therefor, is reserved to officers of the Department of Justice, under the direction of the Attorney General.

This seems to imply some exemptions existed at the time it was written or may have been anticipated in the future. Do any such exceptions exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any comprehensive list, but several exemptions do exist:

- [12 U.S. Code § 5514](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/12/5514) authorizes the Consumer Finance Protection Bureau to enforce consumer financial law.
- [15 U.S. Code § 43](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/43) authorizes the Federal Trade Commission to prosecute violations of the FTC Act.
- [15 U.S. Code § 78d–5](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/78d-5) authorizes the Securities and Exchange Commission to enforce securities laws.
- [42 U.S. Code § 2000e–4](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/2000e-4#:%7E:text=42%20U.S.%20Code%20%C2%A7%202000e%E2%80%934%20%2D%20Equal%20Employment%20Opportunity%20Commission,-U.S.%20Code&text=There%20is%20hereby%20created%20a,of%20the%20same%20political%20party.) authorizes the Equal Employment Opportunity Commission to litigate equal-employment violations.

As far as I know, non-DOJ litigators are limited to independent agencies that aren't headed by a Cabinet-level officer. I assume the idea is that because these agencies are meant to be independent, they need to be able to decide which cases to pursue without DOJ interference.

Comment: "enforce consumer financial law" doesn't mean "prosecute consumer financial cases in the courts"; consider the FBI, for example, which enforces criminal law generally but does not conduct prosecutions.  The same is true of the SEC.  Similarly, the FTC statute authorizes investigations, not litigation, and FTC litigation is [conducted by the Department of Justice](https://www.ftc.gov/enforcement/cases-proceedings).

Comment: I can see why you're reading it that way, but my reading is pretty univesrally accepted as the correct one. That's why all these agencies regularly send their own lawyers into court, and no one says anything about it.

Comment: [Here](https://www.ftc.gov/system/files/documents/cases/randon_morris_complaint.pdf) [are](https://www.ftc.gov/system/files/documents/cases/1_-_complaint_1.pdf) [several](https://www.ftc.gov/system/files/documents/cases/001_complaint.pdf) [examples](https://www.ftc.gov/system/files/documents/cases/digital_income_system_-_filed_complaint.pdf), [if](https://www.ftc.gov/system/files/documents/cases/digital_income_system_tro.pdf) [you're](https://www.ftc.gov/system/files/documents/cases/complaint_-_trend_deploy.pdf) [interested](https://www.ftc.gov/system/files/documents/cases/1-main.pdf).

Comment: Thanks.  Those are all FTC cases, though, so they only address the second bullet point.  I'm still not convinced about the first and third, where the statutory language more closely resembles that of the FBI.  Do the CFPB and SEC have lawyers who appear in court like those of the FTC?

Comment: [I](https://bit.ly/3iOLutj) [wouldn't](https://bit.ly/3iOLhGx) [have](https://bit.ly/2Wq7MKw) [included](https://bit.ly/2Wq7OSE) [them](https://bit.ly/3zHgJ06) [in](https://bit.ly/3iSRKAs) [the](https://bit.ly/3eZELeY) [answer](https://bit.ly/3kZbLYx) [otherwise](https://bit.ly/3BI4L8z).

Comment: Thanks for the information, and for the laugh.

Comment: There are also a lot of exceptions for Article I courts: the IRS argues in tax court, ICE argues in immigration court, the military argues in courts-martial, etc. See also [this article.](https://scholarship.law.wm.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1393&context=facpubs)